# Find/replace regex in Notepad to rearrange and close xml elements

Tags: xml, regex, expression, notepad++

I've got an xml file full facebook messages with elements that need to be rearranged and closed. The structure looks like this:

```
<john>
   <timestamp>Tuesday, August 7, 2012 at 3:53pm EDT</timestamp>
   <message>Cats or dogs?</message>
<hillary>
   <timestamp>Sunday, August 8, 2012 at 1:54am EST</timestamp>
   <message>Ugh, definitely dogs.</message>
```

The `<john>` and `<hillary>` tags need to be closed, and the `<timestamp>` and `<message>` elements need to be swapped:

```
<john>
   <message>Cats or dogs?</message>
   <timestamp>Tuesday, August 7, 2012 at 3:53pm EDT</timestamp>
</john>
<hillary>
   <message>Ugh, definitely dogs.</message>
   <timestamp>Sunday, August 8, 2012 at 1:54am EST</timestamp>
</hillary>
```

I'm new to regular expressions and am having such a hard time with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried ? Also why ? Do you have that much input that you want to automate the process ? Also, would there be some other tags between `</john>` and `<hillary>`. Would there be other tags in `<john></john>` and `<hillary></hillary>`. Is `</hillary>` always at the end of the file ? A lot of questions to take into considiration

Comment: There's about 130,000 lines in total, DEFINITELY need to automate it. There are no other planned tags within '<john>' or '<hillary>'. The file could end with either a '<john>' element or a '<hilary>' element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
search  : (<([^>]+)>(?:\s+|<([^>]+)>[^<]*</\3>)+)(?=(\r?\n)|$)
replace : $1$4</$2>
```

If needed, you can be more explicit:

```
search  : (<([^>]+)>(?:\s+|<(timestamp|message)>[^<]*</\3>)+)(?=(\r?\n)|$)
replace : $1$4</$2>
```

To place the message tags before the timestamp tags:

```
search  : (<message>[^<]*</message>)(\s*)(<timestamp>[^<]*</timestamp>)
replace : $3$2$1
```

Comment: You sir, are a wizard. Tags are successfully closed. Now I just need need the '<timestamp>' and '<message>' tags to switch plages. Can it be done?

Comment: My '<john>' and '<hillary>' tags are now closed (thank you so much), but '(<([^>]+)>(?:\s+|<(timestamp|message)>[^<]*</\3>)+)(?=(\r?\n)|$)' doesn't return anything

Comment: @IanEbstein: I don't understand what you want to do with `<timestamp>` and `<message>`

Comment: I want to rearrange them so that <message> comes before <timestamp>

Comment: @IanEbstein: Ok, it's easy, take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've done an example for you [here](http://regexr.com?374l3) that will work for any name.

```
Search: /<(.*?>)(.*?</message>)/gs

Replace: <$1$2\n</$1
```